# Inaccessible drawable image name in Kotlin?

Tags: android, image, kotlin

I have a problem to access a resource like a (Drawable by its name and not its int id)

In the `MainActivity`class i can't access to the var `drawableResourceId1` and var `drawableResourceId2` inside the two `if statement`, any solutions ?

Note 1:my first image named `a` inside my Drawable and the second image named `b`

Note 2: i'm using multiple screens sizes to support all sizes inside the Drawable for `a` and `b` image like (`ldpi`,`mdpi`,`hdpi`,`xhdpi`,`xxhdpi`,`xxxhdpi`)

**Here is a MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var adapter:FoodAdapter?=null
var listOfFoods =ArrayList<Food>()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(layout.activity_main)

    // load foods
    listOfFoods.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is", a))
    listOfFoods.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is", b))

    var drawableResourceId1 = this.resources.getIdentifier("a", "drawable", this.packageName)
    var drawableResourceId2 = this.resources.getIdentifier("b", "drawable", this.packageName)


    adapter= FoodAdapter(this,listOfFoods)

    gvListFood.adapter =adapter

}


class  FoodAdapter: BaseAdapter {
    var listOfFood= ArrayList<Food>()
    var context: Context?=null
    constructor(context:Context,listOfFood:ArrayList<Food>):super(){
        this.context=context
        this.listOfFood=listOfFood
    }
    override fun getView(p0: Int, foodView: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View? {
        val food = this.listOfFood[p0]
        var inflator = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        var foodView= inflator.inflate(layout.food_ticket, null)
        foodView.ivFoodImage.setImageResource(food.image)
        foodView.ivFoodImage.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(context, Main2Activity::class.java)

            if (foodView.ivFoodImage == drawableResourceId1){
                intent.putExtra(Main2Activity.EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE, AdapterType.ADAPTER_TYPE_1.ordinal)
                intent.putExtra("name", food.name)
                intent.putExtra("des", food.des)
                intent.putExtra("image", food.image)

                context!!.startActivity(intent)

            }
            if (foodView.ivFoodImage == drawableResourceId2) {
                intent.putExtra(Main2Activity.EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE, AdapterType.ADAPTER_TYPE_2.ordinal)
                intent.putExtra("name", food.name)
                intent.putExtra("des", food.des)
                intent.putExtra("image", food.image)

                context!!.startActivity(intent)

            }
        }
        return foodView
    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return listOfFood[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {

        return listOfFood.size
    }

}
}
```

[image: error image]

**Here is Food class**

```
class Food (val name: String, val des: String, val image: Int)
```

Comment: You can pass the value using constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your values using `construction` as you passing your `Adapter`

So, make some changes to your **FoodAdapter** class as mention below-:

```
class  FoodAdapter: BaseAdapter {
var listOfFood= ArrayList<Food>()
var context: Context?=null
var d1:Int?=null
var d2:Int?=null
constructor(context:Context,listOfFood:ArrayList<Food>,drawableResourceId1:Int,drawableResourceId2:Int):super(){
    this.context=context
    this.listOfFood=listOfFood
    this.d1 = drawableResourceId1
    this.d2 = drawableResourceId2
}
override fun getView(p0: Int, foodView: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View? {
    val food = this.listOfFood[p0]
    var inflator = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    var foodView= inflator.inflate(layout.food_ticket, null)
    foodView.ivFoodImage.setImageResource(food.image)
    foodView.ivFoodImage.setOnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent(context, Main2Activity::class.java)

        if (foodView.ivFoodImage == d1){
            intent.putExtra(Main2Activity.EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE, AdapterType.ADAPTER_TYPE_1.ordinal)
            intent.putExtra("name", food.name)
            intent.putExtra("des", food.des)
            intent.putExtra("image", food.image)

            context!!.startActivity(intent)

        }
        if (foodView.ivFoodImage == d2) {
            intent.putExtra(Main2Activity.EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE, AdapterType.ADAPTER_TYPE_2.ordinal)
            intent.putExtra("name", food.name)
            intent.putExtra("des", food.des)
            intent.putExtra("image", food.image)

            context!!.startActivity(intent)

        }
    }
    return foodView
}

override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
    return listOfFood[p0]
}

override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
    return p0.toLong()
}

override fun getCount(): Int {

    return listOfFood.size
    }

   }
 }
```

May Be, Help you

Comment: @andios have you try this

Comment: Thank you so much @UltimateDevil

Comment: Welcome @andios